# get bundle message from context Spring localization

Tags: spring, localization, bundle, message

I tried get translated message with regard locale(ru,uk,en).
But on output have next: ?????? instead normal translate. 
EN message return in normal form.

```
public String getMessage(String key) {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        return context.getMessage(key, null, locale);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check your source .properties files encoding on UTF-8